# When unlocking Windows 7 screen goes black

Tags: windows-7

I often lock Windows and turn my screen off when I'm away for 10 - 20 minutes. Sometimes when I turn the screen on again and I enter my password the screen goes black. Then the system is unresponsive and I can't do anything about the state except pulling the plug.

How can I troubleshoot this and are there any steps I can take to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I've been having the same problem..well, until my video card died.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Microsoft Support article seems to address this problem:
[Windows Vista and Windows 7 Black Screen on Computer Unlock](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2431700).

The suggested solutions are:

1. Turn off the Aero graphics display
2. Update display drivers from the manufacturer's website
3. Turn off security software

If none of these helps, have a look in the Event Viewer for interesting error messages.